# How to generate only o or 1 for a bit column?

Tags: t-sql

I need to fill a bit column only with 0 or 1, I tried the following, which only gave me 1:

```
convert(bit, 2*rand())
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: The expression `2*RAND()` will generate random values between 0 and 2.

Comment: You should be aware that rand() (without passing it a seed value, or always passing the same seed value) will return one value for the entire query - so if you're generating multiple rows, they'll all get the same value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing in any value that's greater than 0 to this expression will yield a 1 every time. In order to do what you want, you need to round the results yourself:

```
select convert(bit, round(1*rand(),0))
```

This will give you a random `0` or `1` `bit` value.

Comment: `rand()` is only evaluated once per query though so all column values will be the same.

Answer (score 5):

If you need multiple rows, and you don't care about the specific distribution of values, something like the following may be appropriate:

```
CONVERT(bit,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(binary(18),newid()),1,1)&1)
```

This will be evaluated once per row

Answer (score 2):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 you can use

`CAST(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) AS int)%2 AS BIT)`

For previous versions you can use

`CAST(CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) AS int)%2 AS BIT)`